# How to update hashed password in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update hashed data password. But the password still not updated.
Here my controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|max:100|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|min:3',
        'level' => 'required|max:75',
        'email' => 'required',
    ]);

    User::create([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        'level' => $request->level,
        'email' => $request->email,
    ]);

    return redirect('data_user');
}
```

And this is update controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findorfail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return redirect('data_user');
}
```

Other field like username, email and level updated. But password still not updated, i don't know what's the problem.
Sorry about my bad english

Comment: In your update method, if you do `dd($request->all())` is there a password input?

Comment: make sure `password` is added in the `fillable` property of the model. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: i have added password in fillable, when i dd($request->all()) there's a password input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findorfail($id);
    $user->password=Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->username=$request->username;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->save();
    return redirect('data_user');
}
```

Comment: when i dd($request->all()) there's no password input

Comment: eh sorry, i forgot to add password name in blade.. and it worked for me, thanks